# iCarousel scaling images when number of images is greater than iCarouselOptionVisibleItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I'm using `iCarousel` to display images clicked by the user and are reloaded dynamically into the carousel. The whole setup works perfectly with default values for `iCarouselOptionVisibleItems` but images start to scale up when the total number of images exceeds 8.

TO try and fix the issue i increased the number of iCarouselOptionVisibleItems to 25 and that temporarily fixed the issue but i know thats not the best solution because the images will still scale after the number exceeds 25. Is there something I'm missing from the documentation that I'm missing?

Here's the code for my icarousel screen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.carousel.delegate = self;
    self.carousel.dataSource = self;
    _carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
}
    - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //return the total number of items in the carousel
        return [images count];
    }

    - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {
        //create new view if no view is available for recycling
        if (view == nil)
        {
            //don't do anything specific to the index within
            //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
            //recycled and used with other index values later
            view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
            view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
        }
        else
        {
            //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
            view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];

        }

        return view;
    }

    - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
    {
        if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
        {
            return value * 1.1f;
        }
        else if (option == iCarouselOptionVisibleItems)
        {
            return 25;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: instead of reusingView you can use new view every time method get called!